# Places autocomplete by lodging and location types

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want Googles autocomplete suggestion to only list lodgings and locations. I've mostly been trying to get the lodging type to work however no suggestions ever appear.

When I remove ac_options from the autoComplete variable everything works fine but ofcourse none of the suggestions are narrowed down by a specific type.

```
    var ac_options = {
        types: ['lodging']
    };

    var input = document.getElementById(this.options.autoCompleteInputId);
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, ac_options);

    //bind to input field
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.gmap);
```

Comment: could you provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ with what what you have so far perhaps?

Comment: I had trouble with jsfiddle so in the end I didnt bother. After a couple of days with this problem I am pretty certain that this currently cannot be done.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think lodging is valid option, as per following link...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

You should try following instead...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction

in place of "pizza near" in example use "lodging"...:)

Comment: The option suggested is not it's appropriate use. An input of lodgings does not return lodging only businesses it matches anything with the exact key word containing lodgings which is different to simply showing lodging businesses only.

Comment: To list lodging business only you can use: var options = {
  types: ['establishment']
};